# multiple inheritance of python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

in [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)
one answer explains the reason why, for this example:

```
class First(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(First, self).__init__()
    print "first"

class Second(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Second, self).__init__()
    print "second"

class Third(First, Second):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Third, self).__init__()
    print "that's it"
```

the answer is:

```
>>> x = Third()
second
first
that's it
```

According to the explanation, it is because:

> Inside `__init__` of `First` `super(First, self).__init__()` calls the `__init__` of `Second`, because that is what the MRO dictates!

What does he mean? Why does calling First super `__init__` will call `__init__` of Second? I think First has nothing to do with Second?

It is said that: "because that is what the MRO dictates", I read https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/
but still have no clue.

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Contrary to the name, `super` does not refer to the superclass. It doesn't matter whether First or Second have anything to do with each other.

Comment: ok. I see. super means following the MRO order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the MRO (method resolution order) of the individual classes is. The only thing that matters (if you use `super`) is the MRO of the class you call the method on.

So when you call `Third.__init__` it will follow `Third.mro` which is `Third, First, Second, object`:

```
>>> Third.mro()
[__main__.Third, __main__.First, __main__.Second, object]
```

So any `super` will look up the next superclass in the MRO, not the superclass of the actual class you're "in".

Comment: Now I understand. It is so confusing.